# Trying to add borders around menu items and make one item a different color

Tags: html, css, menu

Trying to make the background for the "Submit Assignment" button green. Our website is http://www.stephensengineering.com/stephens33/. Solved the issue with the borders and now i need to make the background of the one menu item green. I tried adding css but still no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>Horizontal Navigation Bar w/Rollover Effect</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 

 #navbar ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 10px; 
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right; 
    background-color: #000; 
    } 

#navbar ul li {  
    display: inline; 
    } 

#navbar ul li a { 
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    text-decoration: bold; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: #fff; 
    background-color: #000; 
    } 

#navbar ul li a:hover { 
    color: #000; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    } 

    #navbar{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000; /*To bring the navbar to the top of the stacking context*/
    width: 100%;
    }
    nav.stricky-fixed.fadeInDown.animated{

   top:40px; /*Since this element is already set as relative in the original code,
              the top property places the slideIn menu 40px (height of black nav menu)
              from the top of the page.*/

  }
    .social-icon-wrapper:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.social-icon {
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
--> 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="navbar"> 
      <ul>
        <li style="float:left"><a class="social-icon-wrapper" href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/tonPA8V.png"></a></li>
        <li style="float:left"><a class="social-icon-wrapper" href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/fEvitJl.png"></a></li>
        <li style="float:left"><a class="social-icon-wrapper" href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/UiwMSrt.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:project@stephensengineering.com">project@stephensengineering.com</a></li> 
        <li><a href="+18883000642">888-300-0642</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://github.com">Stephens University</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://github.com">Submit Assignment</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MercedesPennell here's the revised solution. Hope it will meet your requirement.

```css
#navbar ul { 
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0;  
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right; 
    background-color: #000; 
    } 

#navbar ul li {  
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 10px 5px;
  height: inherit;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    } 

#navbar ul li a { 
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    text-decoration: bold; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: #fff; 
/*     background-color: #000;  */
    } 

#navbar ul li:hover { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    } 
#navbar ul li:hover a { 
    color: #000 !important; 
    } 

    #navbar{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000; /*To bring the navbar to the top of the stacking context*/
    width: 100%;
    }
    nav.stricky-fixed.fadeInDown.animated{

   top:40px; /*Since this element is already set as relative in the original code,
              the top property places the slideIn menu 40px (height of black nav menu)
              from the top of the page.*/

  }

.social-icon-wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
    .social-icon-wrapper:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.social-icon {
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

 .submit-btn {
  background-color: green !important;
  border-left: none !important;
  }
```

```html
<!--  -->
<div id="navbar"> 
      <ul>
        <li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/tonPA8V.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/fEvitJl.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/UiwMSrt.png"></a></li><!--  --><li><a href="mailto:project@stephensengineering.com">project@stephensengineering.com</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="+18883000642">888-300-0642</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="http://github.com">Stephens University</a></li><!--  --><li class="submit-btn" ><a href="http://github.com">Submit Assignment</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add a CSS `outline` property, like `outline: 3px solid red;`, to your `#navbar ul li` selector. The border will make overlapping borders around each navigation link. To make your `Submit Assignment` button green, add `style="background-color: green"` to the respective `li` element.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but i want it to have the same style as https://www.nelsonforensics.com/ with the lines from top to bottom other than boxes around them.

Comment: See my edited answer - use `outline` instead of `border`

Comment: no luck :( and i just need one of the menu items for the background to be green

Comment: The website you're referring to does have overlapping boxes around the links. If you only want lines from top to bottom, use only the `border-left` and `border-right` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I made several changes in html and css files. Hope it will work for you.

```css
#navbar ul { 
    height: inherit;
    margin: 0;  
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right; 
    background-color: #000; 
    } 

#navbar ul li {  
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 10px 5px;
  height: inherit;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    } 

#navbar ul li a { 
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    text-decoration: bold; 
    padding: .2em 1em; 
    color: #fff; 
/*     background-color: #000;  */
    } 

#navbar ul li:hover { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    } 
#navbar ul li:hover a { 
    color: #000 !important; 
    } 

    #navbar{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000; /*To bring the navbar to the top of the stacking context*/
    width: 100%;
    }
    nav.stricky-fixed.fadeInDown.animated{

   top:40px; /*Since this element is already set as relative in the original code,
              the top property places the slideIn menu 40px (height of black nav menu)
              from the top of the page.*/

  }

.social-icon-wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
    .social-icon-wrapper:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.social-icon {
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!--  -->
<div id="navbar"> 
      <ul>
        <li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/tonPA8V.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/fEvitJl.png"></a></li><!--  --><li  class="social-icon-wrapper" style="float:left"><a href="#about"><img class="social-icon" src="https://i.imgur.com/UiwMSrt.png"></a></li><!--  --><li><a href="mailto:project@stephensengineering.com">project@stephensengineering.com</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="+18883000642">888-300-0642</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="http://github.com">Stephens University</a></li><!--  --><li><a href="http://github.com">Submit Assignment</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </div>
```

Comment: @MercedesPennell you can try this one.

Comment: Thank you! this helped with the lines, but i am still having issues making the background of the submit assignment button green. :(

Comment: @MercedesPennell I post my revised solution as new answer. Give a try on it. And inform if you face any problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

To make the "Submit Assignment" button green i added a class:

```
<li><a class="active" href="http://github.com">Submit Assignment</a></li>
```

in this example i use "active" as the class and add the following CSS

```
.active {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: green;
        color: beige;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

And for the border, i added "border-left" to archieve what you want

```
#navbar ul li {
        display: inline;
        border-left: #fff 1px solid;
    }
#navbar ul li a {
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        text-decoration: bold;
        padding: .2em 1em;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        /*background-color: #000;*/
    }
```